# ButtonClick to get an Object on SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, uri, parameter-passing, selectionchanged

I have a `SelectionChanged` event and works perfectly, but I want to figure out how to "catch" this selected item at the click of a button they need to pass it as parameter to another page and edit this Item. Here's the current code and button `SelectionChanged` I still implemented because this is what I need.

```
private void listCarros_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox != null && listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //pega o Carro que foi selecionado
            Carro sCar = (Carro)listBox.SelectedItem;

            btnEditCar.IsEnabled = true;
            btnDeleteCar.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnEditCar.IsEnabled = false;
            btnDeleteCar.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I need to edit the selectedItem on this button:

```
private void btnEditCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here I need access to the selectedItem on SelectionChanged event.  
}
```

If you could also tell me how to pass the object as parameter would be perfect.

Comment: Make `sCar` a class level variable and then your button click would be able to access it.

Comment: add a answer to rate this if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a better idea on my comments.  Creating a class level variable is like this:

Notice that `sCar` is declared outside the method, but within the class.

```
Carro sCar = new Carro();
private void listCarros_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (listBox != null && listBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        sCar = (Carro)listBox.SelectedItem;
```

...

```
private void btnEditCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sCar.ProperyYouWantToChange = "Stuff I want to change"
}
```

Comment: This is a good practices? How to pass the object with parameter to another page?

Comment: obviously this requires that both the selection changed and button click method are within the same class.  Its is a good practice, though if you are needing to pass the variable around, then I would need to understand your architecture better

Comment: is the following, the event is on my main page, but I want to select one of the items that are in a list on this page and so the edit button is unlocked, it's done. But the edit page is another, so, I need to pass this object as parameter to another page to be able to write the new data.

Is this it?

Comment: When and how (need answer to both) do you instantiate the new page?  Creating a constructor that accepts `sCar` as a parameter in the new page would be the way to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

> You can do this with binding also
>
> 1.Bind ListBoxItem(Carro Object) to the tag of "btnEditCar" in xaml.
>
> Xaml should be like this

```
<Button Name="btnEditCar" OnClick="btnEditCar_Click" Tag="{Binding}"/>
```

and now in

```
private void btnEditCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Carro sCar=(Carro)((sender as FrameworkElement).Tag)
}
```

This is the good practice,creating a class variable only for temporary purpose is hack

Comment: Okay, but I declared a variable of type car in the App.xaml file and it it becomes a variable that can be used anywhere in the application and file. Then worked perfectly making it more the answer above, in any event, your way works too!